# Discoverer.DiscoverAsync returns "0.0.0.0" as e.Agent.Address

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp, sharp-snmp

I´m trying to use DiscoverAsync method but I´m having some troubles. This is my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        asyncMethod();
    }
    private async void asyncMethod()
    {
        Discoverer disc = new Discoverer();
        disc.AgentFound += DiscovererFound;            
        await disc.DiscoverAsync(VersionCode.V1, new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 192,168,1,255}), 161), new OctetString("public"), 6000);
    }
    private void DiscovererFound(object sender, AgentFoundEventArgs e)
    {            
        Console.WriteLine(e.Agent + ":" + e.Variable.Data);
    }
```

And this is the output:

```
0.0.0.0:0:RICOH Aficio MP C300SR 2.09 / RICOH Network Printer C model / RICOH Network Scanner C model
0.0.0.0:0:RICOH Aficio MP 301 1.06 / RICOH Network Printer C model / RICOH Network Scanner C model / RICOH Network Facsimile C model
0.0.0.0:0:RICOH Aficio MP 2851 1.01 / RICOH Network Printer C model / RICOH Network Scanner C model
```

As you can see, It´s returning "0.0.0.0:0" as agent endpoint, but I think my code is correct because it discovers the id of the three printers I have connected. I have tested multiple versions of the library, indluding the 10.0.0-beta1. For the purpose of my application I need the IP addresses. I would thank you any help in this.

Regards!

PD: I´m using "192.168.1.255" because it throws me a socket exception with "IPAddress.Broadcast" or "255.255.255.255".

Comment: Did you test 9.0.7? 10.x is obsolete at this moment.

Comment: Yes. I have tried with the 9.0.7. For some reason it doesn´t compile in UWP but I obtain "0.0.0.0" with that version too.

Answer (score 0):

This has been identified as [a bug](https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/issues/42) and was fixed in release 9.2.1,

https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/releases/tag/9.2.1